# loop linear regression over samples that contain multiple observations

Tags: r

I have a linear regression model y = 50 + 10x + e, where e is normally distributed.

Every time I fit the model, I'm required to use 20 pairs of x and y values, where x is seq(from = 0.5, to = 10, by = 0.5).

My first task is to fit the model 100 times. In other words, generate 100 samples, where each sample consists of 10 pairs of x and y values.

My second task is to save the intercept and slope of each of the 100 instances of model-fitting.

My un-successful code is below:

```
linear_model <- c()
intercept <- c()
slope <- c()

for (i in 1:100) {
e <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 4)
x <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 10, by = 0.5)
y <- 50 + 10 * x + e
linear_model[i] <- lm(formula = y ~ x)
intercept[i] <- summary(object = linear_model[i])$coefficients[1, 1]
slope[i] <- summary(object = linear_model[i])$coefficients[2, 1]
}
```

Comment: You should be fine if you started with `linear_model <- list()` and then replaced all instances of `linear_model[i]` with `linear_model[[i]]`. You can't make a vector of linear models, but you can make a list of them.

Comment: Thanks @josiber your solution works. Please feel free to copy your comment to an answer and I can give it the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've generated 10 random variables for error but 20 x values so that the dimensions don't match. Either 20 random variables or 10 x values should work.

Below is my trial - note that loops are made only twice (times = 2) while it is 100 in your example.

```
errs <- lapply(rep(x=20, times=2), rnorm, mean=0, sd=4)
x <- seq(0.5, 10, 0.5)
y <- lapply(errs, function(err) 50 * x + err)

myLM <- function(res) {
    mod <- lm(formula = res ~ x)
    out <- list(intercept = mod$coefficients[1],
                slope = mod$coefficients[2])
    out
}
fit <- sapply(y, myLM)

fit
         [,1]        [,2]     
intercept 0.005351345 -2.362931
slope     50.13638    50.60856
```